# Rename [screen] to [gnu-screen]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Many people think that [screen] refers to screen as in monitor screen and use this tag inappropriately. Examples:

- [Screen brightness adjustment not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182856/screen-brightness-adjustment-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)
- [Unable to start X Server with no screens, no xorg.config to edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182279/unable-to-start-x-server-with-no-screens-no-xorg-config-to-edit)
- [Cant change screen resolution in Kali Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181725/cant-change-screen-resolution-in-kali-linux)

I think that [screen] should be renamed to [gnu-screen] to limit this ambiguity.

Comment: Related: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3096/5589

Answer (score 16):

[gnu-screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) was already set up as a synonym of [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen). That means that anyone attempting to tag with [gnu-screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) would end up with [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen).

I have now reversed the synonym so anyone tagging with [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) will get [gnu-screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) instead. I've also retagged the questions you linked to.

Comment: now, to check out what questions are incorrectly tagged.